# How to get status of a record on specific day. SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, join

I'm trying to create a query to see if a record(Alert) was open during a specific time period.

The first table has only the current status of the record.

```
    table: ALERT

    intID  |CurrentStateID| DateCreated
   -----------------------------------
    3      |Closed        | 10/11/2009
```

the second table has the history of the status for the alert.

```
    tblState

    intContextID|strToStateName|datTimeStamp
   -----------------------------------
    3       |Unassigned    |10/11/2009
    3       |Closed        |10/14/2009
```

Here is my desired output:

```
    DESIRED OUTPUT

    DATE        |DAY        |TOTAL_OPEN
    -----------------------------------
    10/10/2009  |Friday     |0
    10/11/2009  |Saturday   |1
    10/12/2009  |Sunday     |1
    10/13/2009  |Monday     |1
    10/14/2009  |Tuesday    |0
    10/15/2009  |Wednesday  |0
```

I was able to write some of the code but I think its the join on the AllDays table that might be wrong.

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2009-10-10';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2009-10-15 23:59:59';

WITH AllDays
AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
        , 1 AS [level]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
        , [level] + 1
    FROM AllDays
    WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
    )
SELECT CAST(AllDays.[Date] AS DATE) AS 'DATE'
    , datename(dw, AllDays.[Date]) AS 'DAY'
    ,ISNULL(TOTAL_OPEN, 0) as TOTAL_OPEN
FROM AllDays
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT s.datTimeStamp AS 'DATE'
        , count(A.intID) AS 'TOTAL_OPEN'
    FROM Alert A
    INNER JOIN tblState S ON A.intID = S.intContextID
    WHERE strToStateName = 'Unassigned'
    GROUP BY datTimeStamp
    ) AS TOTAL_OPEN ON TOTAL_OPEN.DATE = AllDays.[Date]
```

The Alert was open from 10-11 to 10-13 but since I'm joining on datetimestamp the results only show 1 for 10/11.

Here's the schema [a link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d47b0/11/0)!

Comment: Erm...Your table definitions as given don't match the query? As currently written it doesn't parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. one (admittedly hideous) way to do this to create a udf that calculates the open count for a given day like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_open_alert_count] (@date date)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT COUNT(intContextID) as opencount FROM tblState  WHERE strToStateName = 'Unassigned' AND datTimeStamp <= @date) - (SELECT COUNT(intContextID) as closedcount FROM tblState  WHERE strToStateName = 'Closed' AND datTimeStamp <= @date) 
END
```

Then you can do the query like so:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2009-10-10';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2009-10-15 23:59:59';

WITH AllDays
AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
        , 1 AS [level]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
        , [level] + 1
    FROM AllDays
    WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
    )
SELECT CAST(AllDays.[Date] AS DATE) AS 'DATE'
    , datename(dw, AllDays.[Date]) AS 'DAY'
    ,[dbo].[fn_open_alert_count](AllDays.[Date])
FROM AllDays
```

If you don't have permission to create functions you can inline the functionality like so:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2009-10-10';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2009-10-15 23:59:59';

WITH AllDays
AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
        , 1 AS [level]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
        , [level] + 1
    FROM AllDays
    WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
    )
SELECT CAST(AllDays.[Date] AS DATE) AS 'DATE'
    , datename(dw, AllDays.[Date]) AS 'DAY'
    ,(SELECT COUNT(intContextID) as opencount FROM tblState  WHERE strToStateName = 'Unassigned' AND datTimeStamp <= AllDays.[Date]) - (SELECT COUNT(intContextID) as closedcount FROM tblState  WHERE strToStateName = 'Closed' AND datTimeStamp <= AllDays.[Date]) AS TOTAL_OPEN
FROM AllDays
```

This gives me the following output:

```
DATE        DAY         TOTAL_OPEN
2009-10-10  Saturday    0
2009-10-11  Sunday      1
2009-10-12  Monday      1
2009-10-13  Tuesday     1
2009-10-14  Wednesday   0
2009-10-15  Thursday    0
2009-10-16  Friday      0
```

Comment: This probably works but I don't have access to create Functions in the DB. :(

Comment: @VictorUdeshi I've added a version where you don't need to create the function